# how to fix 'jQuery is not defined' error in asp.net

Tags: jquery

i have load the all the jquery files but still getting error like **jQuery is not defined**
this way load the jquery

```
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Utility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

so just guide me how to get rid of this error. thanks

Comment: Have you checked the paths to your scripts? Have you reviewed your network console for loading errors?

Comment: There is insufficient information to determine where the problem might be. Check in the Chrome F12 tools that the files are actually found and downloaded. (also show your entire page code)

Comment: just a hunch, remove `/` from `/Scripts/jquery.js` and just try `Scripts/jquery.js`

Comment: make sure url is right

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```